# module googlesearch returns same result multiple times

Tags: python

when i run my code, the output returns the same result multiple times, when i need to to return different results every time. how would i fix this?

```
count = 0
now = datetime.now()

current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    
def Gsearch(searchQuery): #global count fixed counter, result is still returning the same thing
    global current_time
    global count
    count += 1
    try :
        
        import googlesearch
        for i in googlesearch.search(query=searchQuery,tld="com",lang="en",num=10,stop=10,pause=2):
            print ("(" + current_time + ")")
            print (count)
            print(i + "\n")
            gs = Gsearch(searchQuery)
            gs.Gsearch()
            
    except ImportError:
        print("No module named 'google' found. To install, type 'pip install google' into cmd.")
```

I have tried to change the 'num' and 'stop' functions, have tried using 'break', and enumerate. Nothing works that I have tried, I have looked everywhere online yet have found almost no info on my specific problem, I have looked at the PyPi page of the module yet there is no information on it. Any tips much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont call `gs = Gsearch(searchQuery)` and `gs.Gsearch()` in the function `def Gsearch(searchQuery)`. It makes infinite recursion and won't stop. This recursion makes the search query results always equal by taking the very first result in each call of the function. Just try this :

```
from datetime import datetime
import googlesearch
from time import sleep

global current_time
global count
def Gsearch(searchQuery): #global count fixed counter, result is not returning the same thing
    try :
        count = 0
        for i in googlesearch.search(query=searchQuery,tld="com",lang="en",num=10,stop=10,pause=2):
            current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
            print ("(" + current_time + ")")
            print (count)
            print(i + "\n")
            count += 1
            sleep(1)
            # gs = Gsearch(searchQuery)
            # gs.Gsearch() 
    except ImportError:
        print("No module named 'google' found. To install, type 'pip install google' into cmd.")

Gsearch('your query')
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code was the one that led me to find a solution after tweaking it a bit, so thank you very much!